# React native, get size of bottom tab and set Fixed position for screen

Tags: android, react-native

I am using `import {createMaterialBottomTabNavigator} from '@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs';`

```
export default class TabBar extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {        
    return (
      <Tab.Navigator style={styles.tab}>
        <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} style={styles.window}/>
        <Tab.Screen name="Profile" component={ProfileScreen} style={styles.window}/>
        <Tab.Screen name="Cue" component={NewCueScreen} style={styles.window}/>
      </Tab.Navigator>
    );   
  }
}
```

I would like to set all the child component size so that it is never greater than `width of the screen-tab size` so that no component shall appear BEHIND the tab.

Here is a drawing of what I meant.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Pass `flex: 1` to root component in your screens. Library does it for you, and, unless you use custom tab bar with `position: absolute`, it will not overlap with screen contents

Answer (score 0):

My trick works on react-navigation v4 (right now I don't want to update because the version 5 is still buggy in my opinion), so I'm not 100% sure that this works on version 5, but you can still try to replicate this idea.

The idea is: extract the core `BottomTabBar` and wrap it into a `View` component with `onLayout` prop to get the height!

the code:

```js
import React from 'react'
import { View } from 'react-native'
import { BottomTabBar } from 'react-navigation-tabs'
import { BottomTabBarProps } from 'react-navigation-tabs/lib/typescript/src/types'

// storing height as a module variable
let tabBarHeight = 0

// you can call this everywhere to get the height
export const getTabBarHeight = (): number => tabBarHeight

// wrapping the TabBar into a View which updates tabBarHeight value
export const TabBarComponent = props => (
  <View onLayout={e => (tabBarLayout = e.nativeEvent.layout.height)}>
    <BottomTabBar {...props} />
  </View>
)
```

where you create the bottomTabBar navigator:

```js
const Tabs = createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    ...yourRouteshere
  },
  {
    tabBarComponent: TabBarComponent,
)
```

In your screens you can call exported `getTabBarHeight` to get the TabBar height.

**IMPORTANT NOTE**: in your first screen of the navigator, after the first render  **you will still get 0** as height. So you have to hook to that variable to know when it will change (right after the first render of the first screen)

Answer (score 0):

You can find it in [styles](https://github.com/callstack/react-native-paper/blob/2313c26b24da08d9a778d46608f9e9e6376fdc68/src/components/BottomNavigation.tsx#L980) of [BottomNavigation](https://github.com/callstack/react-native-paper/blob/master/src/components/BottomNavigation.tsx#L980) from [react-native-paper](https://github.com/callstack/react-native-paper) library which is dependency of `@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs`

BottomNavigationHeight = iconContainer.height + iconContainer.marginTop + item.paddingVertical * 2 + labelContainer.height = 24 + 2 + 6 * 2 + 16 = 54

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  ...
  item: {
    ...
    paddingVertical: 6,
  },
  iconContainer: {
    height: 24,
    marginTop: 2,
    ...
  },
  labelContainer: {
      height: 16,
      ...
  },
  ...
});
```

also, you can see height in the inspector
[image]